# Vertex Ordering when constructing a 3D model

Tags: python

So I've just started to learn using PyOpenGL and im just modelling a cube, turns out the correct ordering of the vertices is:

```
Vertices = (
(1,-1,-1),
(1,1,-1),
(-1,1,-1),
(-1,-1,-1),
(1,-1,1),
(1,1,1),
(-1,-1,1),
(-1,1,1),
)
```

So counter-clockwise when z=-1 to counter-clockwise when z = 1.

What is the logic behind the ordering or is that simply just how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing inherently special about the order of the vertices you listed. Typically, assuming `Vertices` is being stored in a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO), you will render the cube to the screen by providing the correct indices to that vertex data in your  `glDrawElements` call. The indices for each triangle that comprises the triangle, however, can be either defined in a clockwise, or a counterclockwise order, of course. This "winding order" could matter if say, face culling, is employed, but otherwise, it is not too important.